# Joomla changing menu item color

Tags: css, joomla, joomla1.5

I published a menu item in the left side - module type "mod_mainmenu"
I want the menu item color to change to some other color when the menu clicks and show the page. To showing the active menu item when corresponding page is viewed

Say 
Menu Item

Page 1
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4

on clicking on link "page1" opens examplesite.com/page1
and the "page1" menu item in the left to show color "green"

Actual  link: http://sample26.marrsinfosolutions.com/
want the left nav say testtimonial, gift voucher etc to change to grey when it is viewed and change back to the default when not viewed

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way to have the present item color changed is by adding a class that will refer to the "active" section of the page, thought you will have to adapt it to your page (its a good practice).

Add rules that will make the selected link look different than the others. Specify an id attribute for the body element to style the “current” navigation tab differently. In the following example the id of the body element has been set to “home”, which makes the “Home” tab the current one. Changing it to “about” would make the “About” tab the current one, and so on.

Example from the page:

```
#home #nav-home a,
#about #nav-about a,
#archive #nav-archive a,
#lab #nav-lab a,
#reviews #nav-reviews a,
#contact #nav-contact a {
background:#e35a00;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:none;
}
#home #nav-home a:hover,
#about #nav-about a:hover,
#archive #nav-archive a:hover,
#lab #nav-lab a:hover,
#reviews #nav-reviews a:hover,
#contact #nav-contact a:hover {
background:#e35a00;
}
#nav a:active {
background:#e35a00;
color:#fff;
}
```

Source: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200501/turning_a_list_into_a_navigation_bar/